# Download file in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In my jsp file, I want to initiate a download and want to continue to the next jsp page while the download happens in the background. In the final page, I want to check the download is 100% complete and then only allow the user to confirm the details.

The problem I am facing is that in the same jsp I can wait till the download is complete but once I move to the next page I have no handle to monitor the download %.

Please let me know if anyone can provide me pointers for the same

THanks

Comment: How about threading in the controller the download.
With a DP Observer to notify when your download is finished ?

Comment: Thank you will try this first thing tomorrow morning

Comment: I resolved this by downloading in another servlet and updating a session variable which the final jsp could access

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by downloading in another servlet and updating a session variable which the final jsp could access